# Store changing data to a date in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here's the spreadsheet I'm working on so that it serves the purpose of keeping track of my goals --> [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Am7vXQqGsqASdF9HZ3RuZTAyZ0lWY3QzTG4ycllHOVE#gid=0)

I'd like to display the data in a graph like the "Test Graph" page shows. I would need a function to check for any updates in the "Goals" page and display it like in the "Test Data" page. I'm a beginner and I don't know how to write Google App Script, I've tried with spreadsheet functions but didn't manage.

Thank you very much! Feel free to download the spreadsheet if you find it useful for you too!